# Add items to page with localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, local-storage

the array is stored in local storage by clicking on the “More” button 2 news is added to DOM
How should I implement this?

```
const ARR= [

           {
               id: 1,
               Name: 'Name1',
               text:'lorem ipsum'
           },
           {
                id: 2,
                Name: 'Name2',
                text:'lorem ipsum'
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                Name: 'Name3',
                text:'lorem ipsum'
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                Name: 'Name4',
                text:'lorem ipsum'
            },
    ];
```

10 obj

here we save the array in localStorage
and where to execute its JSON.parse (localStorage.getItem ('news')) and I don’t understand how to implement work with local storage by click
    ```
     localStorage.setItem('news', JSON.stringify(ARR));

```
class NewsOne extends PureComponent {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            listItem: ARR,
            formAdd: false,
        };

        this.createItem = this.createItem.bind(this);
        this.updateItem = this.updateItem.bind(this);
        this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this);
        this.addForm = this.addForm.bind(this);
    }
    updateItem(item) {
        const { listItem } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            listItem: listItem.map(elem => (
                elem.id === item.id ? item : elem
            ))
        });
    }

    removeItem(itemId) {
        const { listItem } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            listItem: listItem.filter(item => item.id !== itemId)
        });
    }

    createItem(item) {
        const { listItem } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            listItem: [item, ...listItem],
        });
    }
    addForm() {
        const { formAdd } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            formAdd: !formAdd,
        })
    }


    render() {
        const { listItem, formAdd } = this.state;

        return(
            <>
                <div className="box">
                    <Title />
                    <List
                        data={listItem}
                        removeFromProps={this.removeItem}
                        updateFromProps={this.updateItem}
                    />
                </div>
                <button className ="addnews" onClick = {this.addForm}>
                   Add
                </button>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

A class that defaultly displays 2 elements on page.
I tried here to interact with the array from localStorage, but it fails

```
    class List extends PureComponent {
        constructor() {
            super();

            this.state = {
                count: 2,
            }
            this.addObj = this.addObj.bind(this);
        }
        addObj() {
            const { count } = this.state;

            this.setState({
                count: count + 2,
            });
        }

        render() {
            const { count } = this.state;
            const { data } = this.props;
            return(
                <>
                    <ul>
                        {
                            data.slice(0, count).map(item => (
                                <>
                                <Item
                                    key={item.id}
                                    item={item}
                                />
                                </>

                            ))                      
                        }
                    </ul>
                    <button className ="addnews" onClick = {this.addObj}>
                        More
                    </button>

            </>
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/localstorage-list-example-594ug) is an example of how you could implement it. It's using [react-use-localstorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use-localstorage) but you could also implement it in your class. Just load the data into the state in the constructor with `JSON.parse` and update the local storage with `JSON.stringify` & state with the new data. Similar like they did it in the above mentioned [hook](https://github.com/dance2die/react-use-localstorage/blob/master/src/index.ts). If you like the example I could add an answer with some more details.

Comment: Thank you very much